# jQuery Button Not Working

Tags: jquery

I have a back button, the HTML is this:

```
<button id="backButton" name="backButton">Back</button>
```

And the jQuery handling the click is this:

```
    $('#backButton').live('click',function() {
        window.history(-1);
    });
```

When I click on the button, it doesn't run the JS code that it should. Any help?

Comment: Is your code in a dom:ready handler?

Comment: In addition to the dom:ready, is this button injected into the DOM? If not, live() shouldn't be necessary

Comment: @Marcy - Another good point. @Sennheiser - Definitely want to check first that you're inside $(function() { ... });

Comment: window.history is an object not a function.

Comment: Here are the docs for the history object: http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you are using window.history correctly.

```
$('#backButton').live('click',function() {
    window.history.go(-1);
});
```

You could also do:

```
$('#backButton').live('click',function() {
    window.history.back();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/VJFrf/. The alert is working, so it must be something with the window.history .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#backButton').live('click', function() {
        alert('Test');
    });
});
```